# Get all checkboxes without certain class

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I need to find all checkboxes without certain class.
This is what I have and this does not work. I need to check all checkboxes that does not have class named as "features".

```
var value = 'features';
$('input:checkbox[class!="'+value+'"]').attr("checked", "");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `:not`

```
var checkBoxes = $("input:checkbox:not(." + value + ")");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want: [fiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/HFfcP/29/)

```js
var cname = "features";
$('input:checkbox:not(.'+cname+')').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="one" class="features">one<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="two" class="two">two<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="three" class="three">three<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="four" class="features" > four
```